# Gerar saída em csv de um código em python

Tags: python, csv

Espero que possam ajudar. Sou novata no python e minha dúvida é o seguinte. Criei um `regex` que extrai de um arquivo em *csv* as partes dos texto que desejo. Porém quero salvar a saída dessa função em *csv* para comparar com a tabela inicial para saber o quão meu `regex` é bom. Basicamente que pegar a saída da minha função e gerar uma tabela em *csv*. Alguém pode me ajudar? Grata!

Segue abaixo o código. O que eu gostaria de fazer é salvar a lista pms em csv, juntamente com algumas colunas da tabela de entrada(df)

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/b223902594/Documents/Sentenças/codigos/teste.csv', sep=';')

sentenca = df["descricao"] #descrição é uma das quatro colunas da tabela original.

def verificar_padroes_sentenca(lista_sentencas):
regex = r'(julgo .* dias-multa)|(julgo.*\babsolv)|(julgo .* punibilidade)|    (julgo .* Lei)| (julgo .* dias multa)'
for sentenca in lista_sentencas:
pms = re.findall(regex, sentenca, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(pms)
```

Desculpem por não ter passado antes! Sou novata.
Grata!

Answer (score 1):

Para salvar em CSV, você pode usar a biblioteca built-in do Python:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Mais especificamente o método `.write()`:

```
import csv
# abrindo o arquivo para escrita
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam']) # escreve tres strings no csv
```